# Query has_many relationship, contains this and also this

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
# engine.rb
has_many :pistons

#piston.rb
belongs_to :engine
```

Piston has a column, `piston_count` and, of course, `engine_id`

My database has the following 7 records

```
Engine.all
#=> [#<Engine id: 1>, #<Engine id: 2>, #<Engine id: 3>]

Piston.all
#=> [#<Piston id: 1, engine_id: 1, piston_count: 1>, #<Piston id: 2, engine_id: 1, piston_count: 2>, #<Piston id: 2, engine_id: 2, piston_count: 1>, #<Piston id: 2, engine_id: 3, piston_count: 2>]
```

I want to write a query that says, return the `Engine` containing Pistons with a `piston_count` of `1` and also contains a `piston_count` of `2`

I've tried...
    engines = Engine.joins(:pistons).merge(Piston.where(piston_count: 1))
    #=> [#, #]
    engines.joins(:pistons).merge(Piston.where(piston_count:2))
    #=> []

It returns an empty array because active record turns that into one AND clause. However, if I do an OR statement, it will return too many records. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. This takes the intersect of both Active Record Queries.

```
engine_ids = Engine.joins(:pistons).merge(Piston.where(piston_count: 1)).pluck(:id) & Engine.joins(:pistons).merge(Piston.where(piston_count: 2)).pluck(:id)
```

Then go back and retrieve all the intersects.

```
Engine.where(id: engine_ids)
```